# using a statement twice with different binding results

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

is it possible to use a statement *twice* with *different* binding results?
example: the first script includes the second script. 
in firstscript.php the prepared statement make a select and binds the results by variables for the first output. the output could be for example the amount of results. the script includes the secondscript.php.

```php
// firstscript.php
$sql ="SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM table WHERE table.field1=? AND table.field2=?";
$stmt->bind_params("si",$para1,$para2);
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_result($field1,$field2,$field3,$field4);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->num_rows();
while($stmt->fetch())
    {
    //output
    }
$stmt->close();
include(secondscript.php);
```

the secondscript.php reuses the statement-object for making a new select in conjunction with limiting the results. for the output the statement needs other binding results for the output.

```php
// secondscript.php
$limit = " LIMIT 0,5";
//use the same statement from first script in conjunction with $limit
$stmt->prepare($sql.$limit);
$stmt->execute();
/*
// case 1
//without binding results 
while($stmt->fetch())
    {
    //no output
    }

// case 2
//with binding results - like in the first script
$stmt->bind_result($field1,$field2,$field3,$field4);
while($stmt->fetch())
    {
    //output
    }

// case 3
//same statement with *different* bindings
*/
$stmt->bind_result($field3,$field4);
while($stmt->fetch()
    {
    //output - failure; binding error
    //Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement
    }
$stmt->close();
```

how can i assign the reused statement new binding results for the final output?

thanx to all